# CI How To Handle Queries Returning Nothing?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Im building a signing in form for my workplace where users can log in and and clock their hours.

I've done it so that the user goes onto a timesheet and can click corresponding buttons relating to each signing in and out period of the dat e.g. morning break, All of the buttons uses updates and the first button to start the day is the insert button which creates the record with todays date, the current time after which each button press updates that record with new times relating to the day.

The insert button ('sign in') creates a new record each time so needs disabling, so I'm trying model function to check if a record exists with the staff id and date, if it doesn't then perform the normal insert as a new record for the day, if it doesn't i want it to return something like FALSE which i can check against in my controller to point it to a different page instead of a standard success page.

This is my model function : i've guessed that i need to return a variable, not too sure.

```
function clock_in($id, $time, $date) {

    $check -> db -> get_where('timesheet',array('datez' => $date, 'staff_id' =>$id));

    if ($check -> num_rows() > 0) {
        $data = array('id' => null, 'staff_id' => $id, 'clock_in_time' => $time, 'clock_out_time' => null, 'break1_out' => null, 'break1_in' => null, 'lunch_out' => null, 'lunch_in' => null, 'break2_out' => null, 'break2_in' => null, 'datez' => $date);

        $this -> db -> insert('timesheet', $data);
    } else {
        return $check;
    }

}
```

This is my controller :

```
function clock_in() {

    $session_data = $this -> session -> userdata('logged_in');
    $data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
    $data['time'] = date("h:i");
    $data['date'] = date("y-m-d");

    $this -> timesheet -> clock_in($data['id'], $data['time'], $data['date']);

    $this -> load -> view('timesheet/Clock_in');
}
```

i've not attempted this section yet, I'm not to sure on how i go about checking to see if this variable is empty then load a different vue and not insert anything.

All solutions and grateful, i just need the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following changes:

```
function clock_in($id, $time, $date) {

$check -> db -> get_where('timesheet',array('datez' => $date, 'staff_id' =>$id));
$data = array();
if ($check -> num_rows() > 0) {
    $data = array('id' => null, 'staff_id' => $id, 'clock_in_time' => $time, 'clock_out_time' => null, 'break1_out' => null, 'break1_in' => null, 'lunch_out' => null, 'lunch_in' => null, 'break2_out' => null, 'break2_in' => null, 'datez' => $date);

    $this -> db -> insert('timesheet', $data);
} 

return $data; // this will be either empty or will contain data
}
```

In Controller:

```
function clock_in() {

$session_data = $this -> session -> userdata('logged_in');
$data['id'] = $session_data['id'];
$data['time'] = date("h:i");
$data['date'] = date("y-m-d");

$data = $this -> timesheet -> clock_in($data['id'], $data['time'], $data['date']);
if(empty($data)){
    $this -> load -> view('timesheet/Clock_xyz'); // View to load when no data is returned
}else {
    $view['data'] = $data
    $this -> load -> view('timesheet/Clock_in', $view); // view to load when data is returned
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question properly, but if I'm right:

You can use the following function from Code Igniter:

```
$result = $this->db->query("Your query")->row()->id;
```

You can directly check if it is empty, if it exists your object is directly placed into $result.

Hope this helps.

Edit: You could look a this link to see more options: http://magentohostsolution.com/get-first-row-in-codeigniter-return-database-query/